# Like Facebook! Problem getting :contains value from textarea on keypress(e)? "DEMO"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to fire an event on spacebar press if an url is found in the last word typed and kill that event if there is a result so if the user keeps typing... the function doesn't keep on sending requests to the server.  I'm tired and hope this makes sense...  Basically I'm trying to accomplish what facebook has when you submit a post and enter an url beginning with http://.  I've got it working 100% perfect... you can type and type and when an url is entered beginning with http:// it pings the server, grabs meta data, images from page, etc.  But when the user keeps typing, the function seems to go for a loop and freezes because it's still trying to find an url?

Heres the code anyhow below:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
$('#example').keyup(function() { 
if(e.which == 32) {
var body = $('#example').attr('value');
var body = encodeURIComponent(body);
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "get_url.php",
data: "entry="+body,
cache: false,
success: function(html) {
$("#new_url").html(html);
}
});
return false;
}
});
});
```

I know it's messy... still learning jQuery!

Thanks for all the help!  I would like to scan the textarea input as the user types for an url starting with http://, www, or http:// w w w. using jquery, when found trigger the ajax request and stop the function from looking any further for urls... but am currently using regex in php to find url, fetch data, and return it...

Comment: Sometimes it fails like on godaddy.com and will just return the url, title, & description tags... somehow godaddy.com blocks simple php page scrape functions or something?  But facebook fails to fetch images too if you post http:// godaddy.com.

Comment: heres the demo page I'm working on --> http://top10ingoogle.com/js/test.html <-- Just enter a url starting with http:// and wait a few seconds..."need to add a loading graphic! :-)"... doesn't let you keep typing though and freezes afterwards?

Comment: I'm no JS hero, but one tiny thing I'm noticing immediately is that you define the var body twice. Shouldn't that be var body = thatValue; body = encodeURIComponent(body);

Comment: thank you... didn't notice that!

Comment: basically, I want to kill the keypress even/function after it finds a http:// match/result... I've tried doing a little of this with no success --> if(e.which == 32 && $('#example').attr('val').indexOf('http://').last) {

Comment: gimme a sec, testing some things out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#example').keyup(function(e) {                   
        if(e.which == 32) {                     
            var body = $('#example').attr('value');                     
            body = encodeURIComponent(body);                        
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "get_url.php",
                data: "entry="+body,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#new_url").html(html);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

It doesn't trigger on EVERY key pressed on the entire body.
Furthermore I declare the body var only once.

Tested it locally, doesn't lock up anymore, but don't get any usefull response as get_url.php doesn't seem to return anything.

Comment: pretty effecient little script in the works though! :-)  Try pasting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984530/like-facebook-problem-getting-contains-value-from-textarea-on-keypresse-dem and hit spacebar!

Comment: Hey boris try it in firefox instead of Opera 10.0... works pretty good in firefox 3.5!

Answer (score 2):

I probably wouldn't use the keypress event for something like this. Here's what I'm thinking instead:

1. Use the `focus()` event on the
   textbox to trigger a
   `setInterval(...)` callback
2. In the called function, use a regex
   to scan the contents of the textbox
   for a URL
3. If you find a valid URL, call
   `clearInterval()` to stop the
   scanning, while you do an AJAX
   request to get info about the URL
4. When the AJAX request returns,
   update the contents of the textbox,
   and restore the callback so it keeps
   scanning
5. In the `blur()` event of the
   textbox, set a flag that kills the
   callback permanently (i.e. it won't
   get restored, when the current AJAX
   request returns) -- there's no need
   scanning if the user isn't typing
   anything

I'll try and post some code soon, but hopefully, this'll help you get some sleep. Perhaps, you should get some sleep *first*, and then come back to this?

Comment: Didn't think of that. Indeed probably a better approach.

Comment: Thanks alot... I haven't even got into the binding event / interval / callback stuff yet... jQuery is pretty extensive!  Yeah... thats a good idea... my other eye is starting to get heavy!  Hard to program with one freakin eye! :-)

Comment: so I ilke the new function you posted... it's alot quicker in attaining the results... still has that spacebar lag thing goin on after it finds and returns data on an url?  wierd!

Comment: thats working alot better... the spacebar lag if you keep typing is no where near as slow as it was... mmmm... wonder how facebook did it? :-)

Comment: facebook is "jQuery" driven too... so simple and yet so popular!

Comment: @brandon: setInterval/clearInterval are just plain ole javascript. "One-eyed programming" eh? You should write more about that sometime :)